# SQLIte Read / Write Contention

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

In my application, there is a thread that is constantly receiving and writing data to a SQLite database inside a transaction, then committing the transaction when it's done.

At the same time, when the application runs a long running query, the write thread seems to get blocked and no data gets written. Each method uses the same connection object.

Is there way to do an equivalent of a SQL (nolock) query, or some other way to have my reads not lock up any of my tables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a concept error. SQLite works on this way:

> The traditional File/Open operation does an sqlite3_open() and
>   executes a BEGIN TRANSACTION to get exclusive access to the content.
>   File/Save does a COMMIT followed by another BEGIN TRANSACTION. The use
>   of transactions guarantees that updates to the application file are
>   atomic, durable, isolated, and consistent.

So you can't work on this way, because is not really need of work that way. I think you must rethink the algorithm to work with SQLite. Thats the reason your connection is blocked.

More information:

[When use it.](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

[FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html)

[Using threads on SQLite: avoid them!](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6)